# TFS 2005 version control DLLs in the bin folder?

Tags: asp.net, dll, tfs

I noticed that the DLLs in the bin folder for asp.net websites do not seem to be getting saved. When I goto a new computer and get latest I am missing the DLLs.

What is the correct way to fix this ?  Should I create a seperate folder to contains all DLLs ? And then can I somehow tell my bin references to goto that folder to get the DLLs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using third party dlls, you should absolutley consider putting them into TFS...

If those dll comes from another project from the same solution, you should not put them into TFS.

If you use a base class library in multiple solution, I would consider using the build functionality that TFS offers. You can access your latest build from a network share (add this share as a trusted source) or directly access those dll files from TFS source control.

EDIT: you can always go back in time in tfs without having to save whats compiled....

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to check your compiled .dlls in with your source control.  If you have other dlls that are not directly compiled by your application then you should create a library folder in your directory structure that contains then, and check that folder in.

Comment: Sometimes you have to check in your DLLs.  We're in a financial services situation where we need to be able to show what was compiled on a certain date is what was moved to production on a certain date.  The only way to do this is to version control the compiled objects as well.

Comment: Why is this a bad practice? Its more convient to not have to create another folder for DLLs since the bin folder has them already?